# What did Admiral Cain mean?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In **Ressurection Ship**, Admiral Cain orders her XO to assassinate Adama on her command. Her exact order:

> terminate Adama's command, starting with Adama

Usually, *terminating someone's command* would mean firing/incapacitating/killing him/her, but Cain added **starting with Adama**, so I'm not too sure what her intention was there.

Did she mean to merely kill Adama, or also for the marines to shoot the rest of the officers on the Galactica?

Comment: Losing Adama first would be a huge morale killer for the Galactica fleet, especially Galactica crew. He's the biggest threat to Cain in tactics, knowledge, and power. It could also risk martyrdom, but I think Cain was personally vested in Adama dying. And she was certainly willing to use force against any who stood against her.

Comment: That's not his question. @CreationEdge. The question was, what does "terminate Adama's command" mean?

Comment: @CigarDoug My comment addresses that, giving context for Cain's comment. She meant to terminate *him* in order to terminate *his ability command* and to terminate opposition from *those he commanded*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing the rest of the officers would be a tall order. They are all over the ship and could rally support if not executed at the exact same time.

Executing the bridge officers (the command staff) would be a simple mater of pumping poison gas to the C&C room vents (thereby preventing damage to equipment). Maybe even having enough marines loyal to her on the bridge to subdue the bridge security detail and kill Adama, and the few officers on duty in the C&C room.

From there she has control of the ship and thus command over the fleet with relative ease and minimum bloodshed.

Comment: Thanks for answering! For context, she had a team of loyal marines posted to the Galactica. So her intention was to kill all the officers in the CIC?

Comment: Easiest way of taking control, eliminating competition while doing it very, very fast.

Answer (score 0):

The extension of Adama's command was larger than himself, since he is a great leader. People in the CIC would fight against Cain's forces even with the death of the "old man". Simply killing Adama would not resolve the conflicts between Pegasus and Galactica, she would need to make sure that no obstacles were left alive.

Answer (score -2):

Although I agree with Web Head, I think her statement was **deliberately made to be open to interpretation**.There was no question as to what Adama meant when he told Starbuck to pull out her pistol and shoot Cain in the head. Now that is really terminating someones command.